# How can I fix issue with clock being improperly displayed after exiting pause screen?

Tags: python, pygame

I have created maze game in pygame (this being my first). However when ever I enter and then leave the pause screen the clock is stuck on 00:00:-15. What is even wierder is that if I enter and leave the pause screen again the code works the way I intended it to work (continuing the clock at where it was before entering the pause video.

Here is the code which generates the clock:

```
# creates the string that displays time
def get_time(hours,minutes,seconds):
    if len(str(hours)) > 1:
        a = str(hours)
    else:
        a = "0" + str(hours)

    if len(str(minutes)) > 1:
        b = str(minutes)
    else:
        b = "0" + str(minutes)

    if len(str(seconds)) > 1:
        c = str(seconds)
    else:
        c = "0" + str(seconds)

    return a + ":" + b + ":" + c

# creates the time counter
def draw_time(start_time,pause_time):
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    seconds = 0
    current_time = time.time() - pause_time - start_time
    if current_time > 3600:
        while True:
            if current_time - 3600 > 0:
                hours += 1
                current_time -= 3600
            else:
                while True:
                    if current_time - 60 > 0:
                        minutes += 1
                        current_time -= 60
                    else:
                        seconds += int(current_time)
                        break
                break

    else:
        while True:
            if current_time - 60 > 0:
                minutes += 1
                current_time -= 60
            else:
                seconds += int(current_time)
                break

    return [font1.render(get_time(hours, minutes, seconds), True, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255)), get_time(hours, minutes, seconds)]
```

This displays it:

```
screen.blit(text[0], (700, 15))
```

This activates / deactivates the pause screen:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        done = True
        running = False

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
            if pause:
                pause = False
                pause_time = time.time() - pause_time_start
            else:
                pause = True
                pause_time_start = time.time() - game_time - start

        if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            done = True
```

This is the whole code:

```
import pygame
import random
import time

pygame.init()
# all fonts used
font1 = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 49, True)
font2 = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 150, True)
font3 = pygame.font.SysFont("comicsansms", 28, True)

# creates the string that displays time
def get_time(hours,minutes,seconds):
    if len(str(hours)) > 1:
        a = str(hours)
    else:
        a = "0" + str(hours)

    if len(str(minutes)) > 1:
        b = str(minutes)
    else:
        b = "0" + str(minutes)

    if len(str(seconds)) > 1:
        c = str(seconds)
    else:
        c = "0" + str(seconds)

    return a + ":" + b + ":" + c

# creates the time counter
def draw_time(start_time,pause_time):
    hours = 0
    minutes = 0
    seconds = 0
    current_time = time.time() - pause_time - start_time
    if current_time > 3600:
        while True:
            if current_time - 3600 > 0:
                hours += 1
                current_time -= 3600
            else:
                while True:
                    if current_time - 60 > 0:
                        minutes += 1
                        current_time -= 60
                    else:
                        seconds += int(current_time)
                        break
                break

    else:
        while True:
            if current_time - 60 > 0:
                minutes += 1
                current_time -= 60
            else:
                seconds += int(current_time)
                break

    return [font1.render(get_time(hours, minutes, seconds), True, (0, 0, 0), (255, 255, 255)), get_time(hours, minutes, seconds)]

class cell:
    def __init__(self,up,down,left,right):
        self.visited = False
        self.walls = [up,down,left,right]

class labyrinth:
    # generates the maze
    def __init__(self,id):
        self.id = id
        self.walls = []
        self.maze_walls = []
        self.cells = []

        x = 0
        t = 0

        # creates all cell within the maze
        for f in range(22):
            for s in range(28):
                # if command makes sure no cellls are created where the clock is supposed to be
                if not (f in (0,1,2) and s > 20):
                    self.cells.append(cell((x + 8, t, 25, 8), (x + 8, t + 33, 25, 8), (x, t + 8, 8, 25), (x + 33, t + 8, 8, 25)))
                x += 33
            x = 0
            t += 33

        # generates maze using prim's algorithm
        for v in self.cells[0].walls:
            self.maze_walls.append(v)
            self.walls.append(v)

        self.cells[0].visited = True

        while len(self.walls) > 0:
            wall = random.choice(self.walls)
            # checks which cells are divided by the wall
            divided_cells = []
            for u in self.cells:
                if wall in u.walls:
                    divided_cells.append(u)

            if len(divided_cells) > 1 and (not ((divided_cells[0].visited and divided_cells[1].visited) or ((not divided_cells[0].visited) and (not divided_cells[1].visited)))):
                # checks which cells have been visited
                for k in divided_cells:
                    k.walls.remove(wall)

                    if k.visited == False:
                        k.visited = True

                    for q in k.walls:
                        if not q in self.walls:
                            self.walls.append(q)

                        if not q in self.maze_walls:
                            self.maze_walls.append(q)

                    if wall in self.maze_walls:
                        self.maze_walls.remove(wall)

            self.walls.remove(wall)

        for j in range(0,736,33):
            for i in range(0,951,33):
                self.maze_walls.append((i, j, 8, 8))

    # draws the maze
    def draw(self, goal):
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

        for k in self.maze_walls:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(k[0],k[1],k[2],k[3]))

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, pygame.Rect(695, 0, 300, 105)) # clock background
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 255, 0), goal) # finish

id = 0
running = True
while running:
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((930, 733))
    done = False
    color = (0, 128, 255) # color of the walls
    x = 16
    y = 16
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    start = time.time()
    id += 1
    maze = labyrinth(id)
    goal = pygame.Rect(899,701,25,25)
    victory = False
    speed = 4 # movement speed
    pause = False
    pause_time = 0 # time spent in pause menue
    game_time = 0 # time spent playingg

    while not done:
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
                running = False

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    if pause:
                        pause = False
                        pause_time = time.time() - pause_time_start
                    else:
                        pause = True
                        pause_time_start = time.time() - game_time - start

                if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                    done = True

        if pause:
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            pause_text = font2.render("PAUSE",True,(255,255,255))
            screen.blit(pause_text, (468 - (pause_text.get_width() // 2), 368 - (pause_text.get_height() // 2)))

        # the actual game
        if not victory and not pause:
            game_time = time.time() - pause_time - start
            move_up = True
            move_down = True
            move_left = True
            move_right = True
            pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

            # movment
            if pressed[pygame.K_w] or pressed[pygame.K_UP]:
                # checks if their is a overlap with the wall
                for m in maze.maze_walls:
                    player = pygame.Rect(x, y - speed, 10, 10)
                    if player.colliderect(pygame.Rect(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3])):
                        move_up = False
                        break
                if move_up:
                    y -= speed

            if pressed[pygame.K_s] or pressed[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                player = pygame.Rect(x, y + speed, 10, 10)
                for m in maze.maze_walls:
                    if player.colliderect(pygame.Rect(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3])):
                        move_down = False
                        break
                if move_down:
                    y += speed

            if pressed[pygame.K_a] or pressed[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                player = pygame.Rect(x - speed, y, 10, 10)
                for m in maze.maze_walls:
                    if player.colliderect(pygame.Rect(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3])):
                        move_left = False
                        break
                if move_left:
                    x -= speed

            if pressed[pygame.K_d] or pressed[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                player = pygame.Rect(x + speed, y, 10, 10)
                for m in maze.maze_walls:
                    if player.colliderect(pygame.Rect(m[0],m[1],m[2],m[3])):
                        move_right = False
                        break
                if move_right:
                    x += speed

            # checks if player has reached the goal
            if goal.colliderect((x, y, 10, 10)):
                victory = True

            # draws the screen
            maze.draw(goal)
            text = draw_time(start, pause_time)
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 100, 0), pygame.Rect(x,y,10,10))
            screen.blit(text[0], (700, 15))

        # victory screen
        if victory:
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            time_text = font1.render("Time Taken: " + text[1],True,(255,255,255))
            victory_text = font2.render("VICTORY!",True,(255,255,255))
            reset = font3.render("(Press Enter to Start New Game)",True,(255,255,255))

            screen.blit(victory_text,(468 - (victory_text.get_width() // 2), 328 - (victory_text.get_height() // 2)))
            screen.blit(time_text, (468 - (time_text.get_width() // 2), (248 - (time_text.get_height() // 2)) + victory_text.get_height()))
            screen.blit(reset, (468 - (reset.get_width() // 2), (248 - (reset.get_height() // 2)) + victory_text.get_height() + time_text.get_height()))

        clock.tick(60)
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are dealing with two different kinds of time measurement here, instants and durations. What you get from `time.time()` is an instant - it describes a specific point in time. When you substract two instants you get a duration - the time elapsed between those two specific points. By getting confused between the two, you're seeing confusing results.

```
start = time.time()
# ...
pause_time = 0 # time spent in pause menue
game_time = 0 # time spent playingg
```

Here you're saying that start is an *instant*, the moment the game started. You're saying that pause_time and game_time are *durations*. They are intended to be the time elapsed since the start of the game spent in the paused/unpaused mode.

Every frame that you're not paused, you update game_time:

```
game_time = time.time() - pause_time - start
```

Here `start` and `time.time()` are instants, and `pause_time` is a duration. This works, although it is a little awkward to read. Subtracting `start` from `time.time()` gives you the total elapsed time since the game started in either paused or unpaused mode, and subtracting `pause_time` gives the time spent in unpaused mode. Great.

Here's your on-pause behaviour:

```
pause = True
pause_time_start = time.time() - game_time - start
```

So `time.time()` and `start` are again instants. Subtracting them gives you total elapsed time in any game more. Subtracting `game_time` gives you the total elapsed time in pause mode, a duration. I'm not certain this is what you actually want, because the next time you use it is in your unpause code:

```
pause = False
pause_time = time.time() - pause_time_start
```

So `time.time()` is an instant, and `pause_time_start` is a duration. Subtracting them like this will give you another instant, some moment in time before your game started. But you're using this instant like a duration! An instant is *still* a number, but generally it's a pretty huge number. (Technically it's the number of seconds since the epoch, a specific moment in time that is going to be midnight, Jan 1 1970 in most operating systems you'll likely run Pygame.)

Things go obviously wrong when you update `game_time` again:

```
game_time = time.time() - pause_time - start
```

Now that `pause_time` has a bad value, you're trying to add one instant (`time.time()`) and subtract two others. This gives you a huge negative value. When you try to render it, your time rendering code is very confused because it is not expecting negative numbers. It's not displaying "-15" seconds. It's displaying a number like "-1545616400" which doesn't fit on the screen!

The reason it works the *second* time round is that the errors cancel out. This calculation makes `game_time` hugely negative, which affects the next calculation of `pause_start_time`, making it hugely positive, and finally causing the next calculation of `pause_time` to be back to a small duration.

---

You can minimally fix this by deciding what `pause_time_start` is supposed to be and fixing the corresponding calculations. I think you probably meant it to be the *instant* the game was paused. If so, you can update your unpause/pause code:

```
if pause:
    pause = False
    pause_time += time.time() - pause_time_start
else:
    pause = True
    pause_time_start = time.time()
```

At the moment we pause, all we do is remember that instant for later. At the moment we unpause, we add the time we spent paused to the accumulated pause time. Our instants stay instants and our durations stay durations.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally take a slightly different approach to how you keep track of time. It seems like you have a lot of different clock variables to keep track of (`pause_time`, `pause_time_start`, `game_time`, `current_time`). Assuming you don't want to keep track specifically of the amount of time you have the game paused, you could work with just your `game_time` variable and an updating variable, and only update `game_time` when you are playing the game.

```
game_time = 0
last_clock_update = time.time()

while not done:
    if not paused:
        cur_time = time.time()
        clock_update = cur_time - last_clock_update  # get time since last clock update
        game_time += clock_update 
        last_clock_update = cur_time

    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE or event.key == pygame.K_p:
            if pause:
                 last_clock_update = time.time()  # Set this to current time so the next clock update after a pause is accurate

    # Rest of game code
```

What we are doing here is updating `game_time` on each iteration of your loop by calculating the time since the last update -- only if the game is not paused.

Additionally, if you wanted to keep track of how much time you have the game paused (or some other stat), you can just make a new variable similar to `game_time` and add to it in the same way depending on game state.